# Flutter build with different flavours instantly crashes after starting

Tags: android, build, flutter, apk

I have followed the official guide for creating different flavours of my Flutter application.
When I build either of the flavours on my emulator,

```
flutter build apk --flavor a -t lib/main-a.dart
flutter install
```

the app succesfully builds but instantly crashes on startup. I have looked at other solutions but none seem to work.

- I checked if my package names are the same.

android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.flutterclient">
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

flavorDimensions "app"
productFlavors {
    a {
        dimension "app"
        applicationId "com.example.flutterclient"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    b {
        dimension "app"
        applicationId "com.example.flutterclient"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

app/src/main/java/com/example/flutterclient/MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.flutterclient;
```

- I've tried **flutter clean** before building

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Would you mind providing the crash report/log when starting the app?

Comment: I'm not sure where to find these logs. I create and install the apk via the cmd without any error messages. When I run the app on my emulator I only get a message saying "App has stopped working"

Comment: Do you by any chance have a physical device? Anyways, try opening a terminal and type `adb shell` and then `logcat` before opening the app. This should give an indication as to what is happening on the device and with your app.

Comment: Logcat keeps spamming messages in the console. It's almost impossible to see what logs belong to my app.

Comment: Try searching for `flutter` and filter through the output. How does the app behave if you write `flutter run --flavor a -t lib/main-a.dart` in your terminal?